# App crash when initializing firebase to flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hello I'm trying to initialize firebase in my flutter project but the app is crashing. I am using the [code from flutterfire](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics/example/lib/main.dart).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:async';



Future<void> main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Please provide logs

Comment: @RohitSuthar How can I get logs from the phone?

Comment: Make sure you follow the guide in Firebase flutter integration https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios